# How to avoid new line in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a `textView` in android then i call `setText("test test1:")`. The problem is that test1 goes to next line as following :

```
test
test1:
```

I've set width to `match_parent` but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you attach your xml with the question?

Comment: `How to avoid new line in android` Please change to: `How to avoid new line in a TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:singleLine="true"` in your TextView. If you want three dots at the end of the TextView, add `android:ellipsize="marquee"` and in your Java file, initialize your TextView and write `textView.setSelected(true);`